# Find the standard matrix for F: R3 to R3, the reflection across the plane H= {x | 2x+y+z=0}.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> [image: Find the standard matrix for F: R3 to R3, the reflection across the plane H= {x | 2x+y+z=0}.]

I have this problem for my Linear Algebra class and I am not sure how to move forward with the calculations. I am able to do similar problems in R2 but am having trouble in R3.

So far I have been using the formulas:

[T]B = [[T(b1)]B | [T(b2)]B] (B-matrix for T)

[T] = B * [T]B * B^-1 (Standard matrix for T)

Could somebody, please, help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax to make your formulas readable. Thanks.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2406319/265466.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the vector perpendicular to your plane is $v_0 = (2,1,1)^T$. The reflection you're looking for is given by
$$
Fx = 2P_Hx - x = x+2(P_H-I)x = x-2P_{H^\perp}x,
$$
where $P_H$ and $P_{H^\perp}$ are the orthogonal projections onto $H$ and $H^\perp$, respectively. Now, $P_{H^\perp}$ is given by
$$
P_{H^\perp}x = \langle x,v_1\rangle v_1,
$$
where $v_1 = \frac{v_0}{\|v_0\|}$ is the normalization of $v_0$. Now, you only have to find $Fe_1$, $Fe_2$, and $Fe_3$ and put these vectors into a matrix. This will then be the solution.